# I have a 2 passports. I have a long term visa with passport A for country C. Can I enter country C with my passport B to have passport B stamped?

Tags: dual-nationality

I have a 2 passports.
I have a long term visa with my British Passport for Italy. Can I enter Italy with my Malaysian passport using my Italian residency on my British passport to have my Malaysian passport stamped?

Malaysia does not allow dual nationality.

Thanks.

---

According to this previous question it seems possible:

[Can a double citizen with a Schengen residence permit enter the Schengen area on their second passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78509/can-a-double-citizen-with-a-schengen-residence-permit-enter-the-schengen-area-on?rq=1)

It is possible to enter the Schengen zone with a passport different from the passport of the residency permit or long term visa.

Does anyone have any recent experience doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Without the actual country names this is very hard or impossible to answer. It does depend on how much information the countries exchange, whether you can get a visa or entry without visa for country C and likely some more reasons.

Comment: Indeed, we don’t even know if you can enter country C with passport B even ignoring passport A and the long term visa. Also more and more countries use fingerprints or other biometrics at the point of entry, and those will probably point to the long term visa and other passport, so it’s likely that it lay at least cause some confusion and delay, but without the details of at least countries B and C and the type of visa, it’s going to be very difficult to make anything but wild guesses.

Comment: This will depend entirely upon country C, it’s almost certainly irrelevant that country B doesn’t allow dual citizenship.  Country C is almost certainly not going to stamp passport B when letting you enter on passport A, although it’s not totally impossible.  Why would you want them to do that?

Answer (score 1):

**General answer:**

Admission into country C is governed by the laws of country C. A and B's opinion don't really matter. If it's legal to enter country C with passport B, than they will admit you. The fact that you also have passport of country A and a visa in that passport, doesn't matter. If you present passport B at the border, they will only look at passport B. You CANNOT use the Visa in A in conjunction with passport B.

Example: I have US and German passports and a China Visa in my US passport. If I go to China, I can use my US passport with the China Visa. If I present my German passport, I will be declined entry since this requires a Visa which I don't have.

**Specific answer:**

There are currently 7301190 possible combinations of three different countries. All of which may very well have special rules and provision that make your specific case different from the General Answer.

***ADDED since the question has been updated***

> Does anyone have any recent experience doing this?

Yes, but it REALLY depends on what countries are involved. I can enter Germany with my German or US passport. I can enter Italy with either passport. I can NOT enter the US with my German passport.

Comment: Thanks for this. It confirms what I already suspected. I would like to clarify the intention of this question though. I would like a stamp of Country C (Italy) in Passport B since if I enter country B which does not recognise dual nationality, in the case some over-zealous immigration officer at country B may look for the exit/entry stamp of Italy upon entry to Country B. The long term visa is with Passport A but Passport B allows me entry for 90 days. What are my options to enter Italy with passport B? If i "overstay" with passport B will I be deported even with residency with passport A?

Comment: This really depends what countries A and B actually are.

Comment: I have updated the question with the specific countries.

Comment: Malaysians currently don't need a Visa to enter Italy.

Comment: @Afifz is the long term visa actually in the passport, or is it a separate residence permit?  If the latter, just present the residence permit and the Malaysian passport, and ask them to stamp the Malaysian passport (which they might not do since some countries don't stamp long-term residents' passports).

Comment: The residence permit is in the form of an ID card and is not tied to the passport.

Comment: I am aware of that a visa is currently not required to enter Italy with a Malayisan passport but upon exit would there be any problems if i stay over 90 days? If the entry is based on a valid residency an posession of a valid passport independant of the issueing country of the passport used for entry then there is no issue.